# Powershell: Copy Elements from one array to another

Tags: arrays, powershell, xpath

Hi in my first array there are my nodes from a xml.

```
$result=Select-xml -xml $uar -xpath "//test:UAVariable[contains(@NodeId,'ns=1;s=::')][starts-with(@DataType,'i=')]" -namespace $ns  | select -ExpandProperty node
```

now i have to filter this further more like this. And then if both if´s are true delete the element from my array if its possible or copy this Element to a new one.

```
$result | foreach {
    $AttExists = $_.Arraydimensions
    $NodeExists = $_.References.Reference.ReferenceType
    if ($AttExists){
        if ($NodeExists -eq 'HasComponent'){            
         #if this is happening i want to delete this hole Element (Node) in my array is this possible?   
        }
        else{
         #if deleting is not possible i want to copy these Element (Node) into a new array is this possible?
        }
    }
}
```

Tried several things like:
`$_=$null`or whith a counter like  `$newArray[$i] = $result[$j] $i++`
But it dont delete anything or copy it. Can someone help me?
xml data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UANodeSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd" xmlns:ua="http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pv="http://yyy/NodeSet.xsd" xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd">
    <UAObject NodeId="ns=1;s=::" BrowseName="1:::">
        <DisplayName>&lt;Default&gt;</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=2;i=10001</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes" IsForward="false">ns=2;i=20001</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::Program</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:ObjectExtension>
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                </pv:ObjectExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAObject>
    <UAObject ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV" BrowseName="1:Global PV">
        <DisplayName>Global PV</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=61</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes" IsForward="false">ns=1;s=::</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="Organizes">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen</Reference>
        </References>
    </UAObject>
    <UAVariable DataType="ns=1;i=100000" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug" BrowseName="1:gFahrzeug" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="-1">
        <DisplayName>gFahrzeug</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=1;i=100005</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="ns=1;i=100010" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug" BrowseName="1:Kraftfahrzeug" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="-1">
        <DisplayName>Kraftfahrzeug</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=1;i=100015</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.PKW</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=3" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW" BrowseName="1:LKW" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="1" ArrayDimensions="2">
        <DisplayName>LKW</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[0]</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[1]</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=3" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[0]" BrowseName="1:LKW[0]" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>LKW[0]</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[0]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=3" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[1]" BrowseName="1:LKW[1]" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>LKW[1]</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gFahrzeug.Kraftfahrzeug.LKW[1]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
</UANodeSet>
```

Code:

```
[xml]$uar = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\strobel.ma\OneDrive - GEA\Desktop\XML to String\OpcUaMap(3)_28_07.uar'

$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($uar.NameTable) #asdf

$ns=@{GEA="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd";
    ua="http://br-automation.com/OpcUa/configuration/NodeSet.xsd";
    xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd";
    xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    pv="http://br-automation.com/OpcUa/PLC/PV.xsd"}

$result=Select-xml -xml $uar -xpath "//GEA:UAVariable[contains(@NodeId,'ns=1;s=::')][starts-with(@DataType,'i=')]" -namespace $ns  | select -ExpandProperty node

$result | foreach {$_.NodeId = $_.NodeId -replace 'ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:'}

$result | foreach {$_.NodeId = $_.NodeId -replace 'ns=1;s=::'}

$result | foreach {
    $AttExists = $_.Arraydimensions
    $NodeExists = $_.References.Reference.ReferenceType
    if ($AttExists){
        if ($NodeExists -eq 'HasComponent'){            
         #if this is happening i want to delete this hole Element (Node) in my array is this possible?   
        }
        else{
         #if deleting is not possible i want to copy these Element (Node) into a new array is this possible?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sample data.. or we’d just have to guess. Try and put more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you a naive approach and just create a new $result2 object where you store exactly what you need

I guess the default System.Array type should be good enough:

declare the new variable where to store items:

```
$result2 = @()
```

and store in it whatever you want by using in your foreach loop the following:

```
$result2 += $_
```